# In the Democratic Party Presidential Primaries, how is the allotment of pledged PLEO delegates to each candidate determined?

Tags: united-states, primaries, democratic-party

In the primaries, some of each state's delegates are legally bound "pledged" party leaders and elected officials (PLEOs), as opposed to the unpledged PLEOs that are commonly know as superdelegates. How are these pledged PLEOs chosen? According to Wikipedia:

> Under Rule 9.C, the pledged PLEO slots are allocated to candidates based on the results of the primaries and caucuses

But that is really vague. Are pledged PLEOs assigned as if they were just more regular delegates, or are they assigned in some way that is based off the primary results of each state, but in a different manner than the regular delegates?